# @solana/web3.js Is there an API for ERC721 Metadata?

Tags: token, metadata, web3js, solana

Given a token mint address, I'm looking for a way to get access to the metadata of an ERC721 token. Is there an API in @solana/web3.js?

Comment: do you have an example of the token mint address? Solana is different to ERC standards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solana stores token metadata at an address that is derived from the original token's address as per
https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#hash-based-generated-program-addresses

The reference code is in rust, here is the implementation from `@solana/web3.js`.
([source](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/5197d1bf3a6ce41c9e8b5e9b058ed244d8685aaf/src/publickey.ts#L171-L191))

```js
  static async findProgramAddress(
    seeds: Array<Buffer | Uint8Array>,
    programId: PublicKey,
  ): Promise<[PublicKey, number]> {
    let nonce = 255;
    let address;
    while (nonce != 0) {
      try {
        const seedsWithNonce = seeds.concat(Buffer.from([nonce]));
        address = await this.createProgramAddress(seedsWithNonce, programId);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof TypeError) {
          throw err;
        }
        nonce--;
        continue;
      }
      return [address, nonce];
    }
    throw new Error(`Unable to find a viable program address nonce`);
  }
```

Note that the metadata is encoded in base64, using the [borsh library](https://github.com/near/borsh), as per https://docs.metaplex.com/nft-standard#token-metadata-program.

Here is a concise implementation to retrieve and parse metadata using only borsh and @solana/web3.js
https://gist.github.com/dvcrn/c099c9b5a095ffe4ddb6481c22cde5f4

Finally, MagicDen has an endpoint that returns the metadata:
https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/rpc/getNFTByMintAddress/DugthRKbQZRMcDQQfjnj2HeSjz2VARPC8H9abxdNK2SS

Comment: Or use the metaplex js library - https://docs.metaplex.com/development/clients/js-sdk/getting-started

Comment: https://docs.metaplex.com/sdk/js/examples#metadata is the updated link to @SergiyKozachenko's comment

Comment: Is API of MagicEden public and free to use, I can't find any info about it.

Comment: @Farid I don't believe the endpoint is meant for public use but it's handy to use while testing.

Comment: @KartikSoneji thanks for the answer. Would be great if they open it public

Answer (score 2):

No there's currently no API for that, however the [phantom wallet](https://phantom.app/) uses the [metaplex](https://www.metaplex.com/) on-chain program at: `"metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"` to get the info it needs about the NFT which is hosted on [arweave](https://www.arweave.org/) & the corresponding data account.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll take a look at it and build something on my own then.

Comment: This worked for me: https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/rpc/getNFTByMintAddress/DugthRKbQZRMcDQQfjnj2HeSjz2VARPC8H9abxdNK2SS

Answer (score 0):

No, but one is available via the Blockchain API here: [https://docs.blockchainapi.com/#tag/Solana-NFT/paths/~1v1~1solana~1nft/get](https://docs.blockchainapi.com/#tag/Solana-NFT/paths/%7E1v1%7E1solana%7E1nft/get)

You just supply the mint_address and get back the metadata. Pretty simple!